# How to convert date of string format to another string format in swift(ios)

Tags: ios, swift, string, nsdate, nsdateformatter

I have a string "**2020-01-01T00:00:00**". How shall I convert it to another string of format **"01-Jan-2020"** in swift (iOS)?

The conversion is from `String` to `String`.

Comment: Use a `DateFormatter` to convert the `String` to a `Date` and the use another `DateFormatter` to convert that to the `String` format you want - so you actually have two questions, both of which have been answered many times before - I suggest trying something first then, if you still have problems, post a question with the work you've tried

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
let inputDate = "2020-01-01T00:00:00"

let dateFmt = DateFormatter()
dateFmt.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss"

if let date = dateFmt.date(from: inputDate) {
    dateFmt.dateFormat = "dd-MMM-yyyy"
    print(dateFmt.string(from: date))
}
```

Answer (score 1):

try below function

```
func convertDateFormater(_ date: String, current_formate : String, expected_formate: String) -> String{
    let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = current_formate
    let date = dateFormatter.date(from: date)
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = expected_formate
    return  dateFormatter.string(from: date!)
}
```